# TextInputLayout Change Theme

Tags: android

Does anyone know how to change the TextInputLayout from the light theme to the dark theme as seen in the design spec linked below?

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

[Design Spec TextInputLayout](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-input)

Comment: Please follow the link: http://blog.stylingandroid.com/textinputlayout/

Comment: In the link you have mentioned, they have changed the background and not the theme of `TextInputLayout`. I would suggest you to make your text partially transparent to adopt with the background. Refer this https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/typography.html#typography-other-typographic-guidelines

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using material design library, like described here:

https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-fields

Then let your App theme extend some theme which uses dark mode. For example:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```